# stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device (/dev/ttyUSB0 usb 2-1.1: cp210x converter)

Tags: usb, serial-port

I have a USB-WDE1 data collector connected to my Ubuntu box. Everything worked well for years, until I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. Since then, I get:

```
sudo stty < /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 -brkint -opost -onlcr -echo
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

`dmesg` shows:

```
[    2.511885] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    2.511892] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.512198] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.783626] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.878364] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[    2.878369] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.878372] usb 2-1.1: Product: ELV USB-WDE1 WetterdatenempfÃ¤nger
[    2.878374] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[    2.878376] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 6053WWMG4VANDBTE
[    2.951635] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    3.048665] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
[    3.048670] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    4.929412] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    5.974343] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    5.974376] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    5.974401] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    5.983051] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[    5.983079] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x  
[    5.984283] usb 2-1.1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

`lsusb` shows:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x     UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

An `ls` command gives this:

```
$ ls -al /dev/ttyU*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 aug  4 15:01 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have a similar problem:

```
xpra attach ssh:sophia@192.168.2.231:100
xpra client version 0.12.3
zofie@192.168.4.241's password: 
2016-10-08 19:22:47,401 PyOpenGL warning: missing accelerate module
2016-10-08 19:22:47,401 PyOpenGL warning: missing array format handlers: numeric, vbo, vbooffset
2016-10-08 19:22:47,402 OpenGL Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
2016-10-08 19:22:47,788 detected keyboard: rules=evdev, model=pc105, layout=cz,il
2016-10-08 19:22:47,793 desktop size is 1366x768 with 1 screen(s):
2016-10-08 19:22:47,794   ':0.0' (359x201 mm) workarea: 1366x744
2016-10-08 19:22:47,794     LVDS (270x150 mm)

stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

...
```

I also do not know why this xpra freezes...